# Unexpected Edge Loop selection in Blender 2.80

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, edges

I'm creating my first donut in Blender 2.80, to get used to the new release of the program and become better at modelling. That also means getting accustomed to new/ altered keyboard shortcuts and the like.

I'm using blender-2.80-linux-glibc217-x86_64 package on Linux Mint 18.1.

To my understanding, many people have been experiencing problems with Edge Loop selection. I had such a problem myself, but by changing the keyboard shortcut in
Preferences -> Keymap -> 3D View -> Mesh -> Mesh (Global) -> Loop Select
to
(Press **Alt + Cmd**) + **LMB**
I can make an edge loop selection.

The thing is, the "direction" of the selection is wrong. What I mean by that is, when selecting an edge, instead of selecting the edges that are "in line" with it, the program selects the edges parallel to the original. Like, it selects the edge on the other side of the same face and so on.

I don't believe it's normal, nor is it the intended use of edge loops. It could be useful in some scenarios, but not the typical one. That said, it would be nice if I could toggle between the two selection modes (the typical edge loop and this "unexpected" one)

[image: Screenshot of what is being selected after performing an edge loop selection]

Thank you for helping me out with this donut.

Comment: Try just alt+lmb.

Comment: This is expected behavior for Alt+Cmd (or Alt+Ctrl). Try using Alt alone instead.